# How fast are liquidation bots?

Tags: bsc, bscscan, flashbots, compound-protocol

Wondering how liquidation bots work in general in terms of looking for possible liquidations.

Was trying to monitor some unhealthy addresses on Venus BSC with Comptroller.getAccountLiquidity() function iterating the requests each second, however these addresses were always liquidated with no chance for me to catch them by the above mentioned function. The only explanation would be that those addresses are being liquidated between my function calls, but it is less than 1 sec. How is that possible then?

Answer (score 2):

I am usually able to get the liquidation in the block after the oracle update is written on chain from Chainlink.

By checking once per second you could query multiple times for the same block, and then miss a block potentially.  You want to subscribe to the new blocks so that you only check when there is a new block with a potentially different oracle price.

Basically:

1. Monitor new blocks for price drops / bad troves.  Only need to check once per block because the system uses the on-chain price for liquidations, so you just monitor that.
2. Once liquidatable trove(s) are found, construct transaction that will carry out the liquidation on-chain.
3. Simulate the transaction locally.
4. If successfully simulated, submit transaction via flashbots relay and hope that your miner tip is high enough to get it included. This submits it directly to the miners and bypasses the public mempool, preventing you from being front run, among other things.
5. The miner will simulate the TX as well, and if included, it will be included at the top of the block in position one and be basically guaranteed to succeed.
6. You do not pay any gas cost for failed / unincluded transactions w/ flashbots.
7. Generally a contract will be used to split the profit between you and the miner.

You are able to target multiple different blocks in the future with flashbots as well as create bundles with multiple transactions of your own or from existing mempool transactions.

You can target multiple blocks, like this:

```
const bundlePromises = _.map([blockNumber + 1, blockNumber + 2], targetBlockNumber =>
    this.flashbotsProvider.sendRawBundle(
    signedBundle,
    targetBlockNumber
))
await Promise.all(bundlePromises)
```

Good luck, it's a battle out there!! :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes sense

Comment: Does this flashbot thing apply only to PoW chains? As BSC is PoS, it should be different then

Comment: @Rigg -- Flashbots themselves operate only on ETH mainnet for now, but Marlin has a flashbots-compatible relay on Polygon.  See: https://www.marlin.org/docs/

Bloxroute offers private relays, which are essentially flashbots alternatives, IE: they take your TX and route it to the miners without it going through the public mempool. 
 They do this for ETH/BSC/Polygon (some others offer this service as well for other chains including AVAX/FTM - see https://docs.snowsight.chainsight.dev/).

Comment: @Rigg Your question was about bsc and flashbot does not work on bsc. Liquidations on bsc are extremely, extremely competitive. Think less than 1 ms competitive (yes, that's 1/1000 second). Not really profitable anymore since there is too much competition.

Comment: @Undead8 that is not really true.  Typical liquidations are going to backrun the oracle update and then those will potentially be frontrun by generalized frontrunners.  You have basically that block to get in or detect a pending liquidation and frontrun.  So, on BSC, approx 2 seconds.  Aka an eternity.  You need to heavily obfuscate your contract calls to try and confuse the generalized frontrunners.  They are absolutely brutal.